# Track onchange selections in a menu jpg

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm not a javascript guy and have run into an issue configuring Google Analytics to track image downloads as and event.  The client has a site that uses a onChange call that pulls a lite java-script that then send the end user to the image page.  is there a easy way to fix the following to track events in Google.  Everything that I have tried failed.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function doIt(theURL)
{
var myPop = window.open(theURL)
}
</script>

<select name="menu2" onchange="if (this.selectedIndex != 0)     doIt(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option selected>Select screen resolution:</option>
    <option value="../images/x.jpg">1600 x 1200</option>
    <option value="../images/y.jpg">1280 x 960</option>
    <option value="../images/zx.jpg">1024 x 768</option>
    <option value="../yz.jpg">800 x 600</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, tracking events with Google Analytics is as simple as calling this function at the right moment:

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)
```

So in your case that could go into `doIt`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function doIt(theURL)
{
  _trackEvent("downloads", "images", theUrl)
  var myPop = window.open(theURL)
}
</script>
```

Or you could consider passing the width or height of the selected image into `doIt` too and then use that as the `value` (fourth parameter to `_trackEvent`). This parameter shows up as a numeric value in the Google Analytics dashboard, so it'll be summed and aggregated (not too useful for you) and you can numerically sort on it.

Comment: Frank thank you, i have the same experience.  I just plugged _trackEvent into doIt and broke the the doIt functionality. I've been down the road of inserting variants of the tracking code wherever it seemed logical and have had the same out come for a few hours.

Comment: Unfortunitly, a more traditional even such as; 'code'<a href="imagey.png"  target="_blank" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Calendar4', 'Download', 'December2012 1600'])">picture</a>

Comment: OK. But the logic there is the same, it just means that the actual call to GA happens "in the background". Does that `_trackEvent` make it into the `gaq`? If so, how do you know it's not working? Keep in mind that the events may take some time to show up in the GA dashboard.

Comment: I know that it isn't working because the '_trackevent' does not make it into the gaq & also afterI installed the code that was recommended  'onChange' no longer triggers the link opening in a new window from teh 'doIt'.   Thank you again, any help is appreciated.